# Find the distance of a vertex from the incentre of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image: Diagram]$F$ is the incentre of $\Delta ABC$. $AF$ is joined to meet $BC$ at $D$ and the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at $E$. If $ED = 4cm$ and $DF = 3cm$, find $8AI$.

MY WORK :-
Regarding this question I could think of only 2 formulas :
${AF\over FD} = {AC+AB\over BC}$ and $AB*AC = BD*DC + AD^2$ however none of them are helping in finding the solution. I feel as if the solution is revolving around these formulas, but still I am not able to reach to a fruitful end.

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: is there any flaw @Nikhil ?

Comment: ya ofcourse that's pretty much obvious @cosmo5

Comment: @ShantanuDe Ok great you completely changed the question. Can you also add a diagram?

Comment: i have added @cosmo5

Comment: @arnavde1220 +1 for improving the question. Your question is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [Fact 5](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Fact5/Fact5.pdf) that $E$ is center of circle passing through $B,F,C,J$ where is $J$ is $A$-excenter. Thus $$EF=7=EB=EC=EJ$$

Now by power of point of $D$ wrt these two circles

$$AD\cdot DE =BD\cdot CD= DF\cdot DJ$$

$$\Rightarrow (AF+3)\cdot 4 = 3\cdot 11$$

$$\Rightarrow 8AF = 42$$

Comment: i didn't understand, can you like elaborate with a figure, maybe @cosmo5

Comment: @ShantanuDe I have linked the proof that has a diagram. Click on $\text{Fact 5}$.

Comment: so you're basically talking about the lemma, right ??

Comment: Yes. We directly use this and then power of point D.

Comment: okay got it, thanks